# angularjs post web service dropdown

Tags: html, mysql, angularjs, rest

I have created a web application with Eclipse where I use AngularJS and REST GET web services. Through the web services I query my MySQL database for data and send the values to my html page through controlles http GET controllers. 
I successfully show dropdown lists with the database values in my HTML page. Now I want to send the selected items for each dropdown list back to a java page so that I can create a new query that will produce some new data. But I don't know how I can do this second part, can someone help me with it?

Thanks in advance!

this is part of my  html page

```
 <div id="three" ng-controller="mycontroller"> 
            <table class="table table-hover">
                <tbody>
                  <select ng-model="selecteditem">
                   <option ng-repeat="item in items">
                       {{item.itemname}}
                       </option>
                       </select>
                </tbody>
            </table>
                  <b>You selected: {{selecteditem}}</b>
          </div>
<script>
 var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
  app.controller('showitems', function($scope, $http) {
             $http.get('http://localhost:8080/myproject/REST/WebService_items/GetItems').
             success(function(data) {
                 $scope.items = data;
                })
                .error(function() {
                    $scope.items  = "error in fetching data";

                });
        });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div id="three" ng-controller="mycontroller"> 
            <table class="table table-hover">
                <tbody>
                  <select ng-model="selecteditem">
                   <option ng-repeat="item in items">
                       {{item.itemname}}
                       </option ng-click="callTheFunction(item.itemname})">
                       </select>
                </tbody>
            </table>
                  <b>You selected: {{selecteditem}}</b>
          </div>
<script>
 var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
  app.controller('mycontroller', function($scope, customService) {
    $scope.items = [{itemname:'apple'},{itemname:'mango'}]
    $scope.callTheFunction=function(itemSelected){
      customService.restCallToJava(itemSelected)
  }
    app.service('customService',['$http', function($http) {
      var restCallToJava= function(sensorObj){
        return $http.post('/api',sensorObj);
      }
    }])
  
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <label>example</label>
  <md-select id="example" ng-model="vm.list.example" required>
    <md-option ng-repeat="unit in vm.list" value="{{example.id}}">{{example.name}}</md-option>
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for both answers! My main issue is not how to show the items in the drop down lists, I have done that. I want to send the selected items to a Java page of my project through a REST web service function, so I don't know how to write the angularjs code in my HTML page that will send push/post the items in the web service's URL.